# Gatling: Concurrent execution within a scenario

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am trying to test the loading time of a home page.
The sequence of HTTP requests made by browser when loading the home page is like
A -> B -> [C, D, E]

Which is to say

- B executes after A's response is received and
- C, D, E starts concurrently after B's response is received.

I tried the below approach to simulate this:

**Approach 1**

Have one scenario each for `A, B, C, D, E`.
All of the scenarios are configured with say 50 users. I tried this:

```
A.inject().andThen(B.inject.andThen(C.inject(), D.inject(), E.inject()))
```

The problem with this is that, B starts only after all users of A has stopped. This does not simulate the home page loading accurately because I expect a user who has finished A to start with B without waiting for other users.

**Approach 2**

I created a single scenario with all the http requests.

```
exec(A).exec(B).exec(C).exec(D).exec(E)
```

This would mean that for example, D executes only after C's response is received. This is not right.

What is the best way to solve the problem?

Comment: Concurrent requests in Gatling is still an [open issue](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3783).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how Gatling works, nor do your actual web clients.

You should have 1 single scenario with users performing request A, then request B, then requests C, D and E concurrently using [resources](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_request/#resources).

```scala
val scn = scenario("foo")
  .exec(requestA)
  .exec(requestB
    .resources(requestC, requestD, requestE)
  )
```